# Macports IDLE unresponsive

Tags: python-2.7, macports, python-idle

I have just installed Macports for a short course I am planning to do.
IDLE does not open whether I launch it from Terminal or Finder.

Just for clarification, I am issuing `idle2.7` to  launch it from terminal.

I have tried [this solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58921/python-idle-from-macports-cant-start) but nothing happened.

*Python & IDLE 2.7.11

Comment: Installing py27-tkinter makes it work for me. Please provide the output of `port installed py27-tkinter` and the output of `idle2.7` when you try to start it on the terminal. Additionally, I don't exactly know what features idle has over ipython, but ipython may also provide what you need.

Comment: I have no idea if Macports installs an `idle2.7` script.  Try `python -m idlelib.idle`, which should always work.

Comment: `The following ports are currently installed:
py27-tkinter @2.7.11_2 (active)`